# Magento 2 how to change label for firsname field in checkout page?

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 how to change label for firsname field in checkout page.
need to change in code level don't want to translation sheet

Comment: Is It working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you want to change it by code :

Create **di.xml** file for plugin create :

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="first_name_change" type="Vendor\Moudle\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

Create **LayoutProcessor.php** file :

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['label'] = __('My Name'); 

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: Great,It's working. Thank you so much @Rohan Hapani

Comment: Happy coding !!